# Firebase tools installation fails with npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I'm trying to install the Firebase CLI and I'm getting this error:

> WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/

And then this:

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js'

I tried `sudo`, then:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools --unsafe-perm
```

but it still doesn't work.

How to install firebase tools with out error?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Yes, This error was on MacOS 10. I reinstall the OS and it starts to work.